# Listening to Joypad Input in Bash Script

Tags: bash, scripts, input, button, joystick

I'm looking to write a script to kill a game process with a button combo on a joypad. Is there a way I can listen for joypad button presses in a bash script?

Comment: Presumably you have already installed the software to control your gamepad.  What is the gamepad type, XBox, or Playstation or something else?

Comment: Also are you using the gamepad with native Linux games or using some other gaming platform like Steam, for instance?

Comment: I'm using an Xbox controller for native standalone linux games. I'm not using any kind of launcher or gaming platform.

Comment: OK I had and Xbox controller, but looks like I don't any more, to try it out, but if the software you use to control your gamepad is xboxdrv then it is definitely possible to listen for your gamepad events if you don't have that installed it can be installed with  $ sudo apt install xboxdrv then consult the man pages it states "It is also  possible for xboxdrv to read input data directly from an event device and that you can write wrapper scripts around xboxdrv See [Writing  Start-Up Scripts for Games] for more information."

Comment: I also forgot to mention, xboxdrv would have to be run as a daemon to enable you to listen to input events.